# Effect of observer orientation and position on perceived angle

Tags: geometry

As an observer moves away from normal to a surface, there is a change in the perceived angle at which 2 lines meet. As far as I can tell, the change in angle depends on 3 factors:

1. Change in pitch angle (away from normal)
2. Change in roll angle (away from normal)
3. How far from parallel / perpendicular to the observer the lines are (if a line is oriented vertically or horizontally there will be no change in its perceived angle as the observer moves)

As I can't figure out a formula that describes this behaviour I'd appreciate some guidance.

To give some background, in a computer vision application I know that I'm looking for a right angle corner but the position and orientation of the corner with respect to the camera is unknown. I can identify all the edges in the image using canny edge detection but I can't identify which of the edges are the ones I care about and so I'm hoping this will give me a way of down-selecting.

[I don't have enough enough reputation to post an image so I've linked an image instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdOq2.png). In the linked image, the corner formed by BAC is 90 degrees but the observer perceives it to be 126.45 degrees. The observer pitch is 60 degrees from normal and their roll is 0 degrees from normal. The line AB is 40 degrees from vertical

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It looks/sounds as if the camera is described using a point projection model? Whether or no, it should be straightforward to calculate (in terms of Cartesian coordinates) angles at which lines meet in the plane "seen" by the camera. That said, I'd expect right angle detection relies to a large extent on semantics of the scene, not just on geometry seen by the camera.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewD.Hwang. I'm pretty new to this so I hadn't come across the point projection model before. From a bit of googling it looks like there will probably be too many unknowns to do what I'd intended but I hope to have a bit of a play and see how far I get.